# Joomla show only modules on the article, but not the content of the article itself

Tags: joomla, module, article

The title pretty much explains itself. I want to display some modules on the article, but not the content of the article, so the page consists only of the modules. It doesn't work if I leave it blank as it still remains a blank paragraph. I just want to display the modules. I've seen some workarounds but I think they were for a lower version of Joomla!. Mine is 3.3.3
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your menu item type: `Menu Item Type: Articles -> Featured Articles`.

In the `Layout` tab you have to set:

```
Leading Articles: 0
Intro Articles: 0
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a Featured Articles menu item for this page, and set it to display 0 Leading and Intro Articles and Links. The component will output no content from com_content and you can only display the modules you want into any position.

Alternatively, you could create an article which would load modules in its body, with the "**Load Module**" content plugin, and have it display these modules without other content.

For this to work you need to have the "Load Module" plugin enabled. The syntax to load modules is either {loadposition myposition}, that loads any modules assigned to that position for the current menu-item, or {loadmodule modulename} that loads one single module by module name.

[Load Module documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F)

Comment: Or make an empty article and don't display title, name or anything else and link that.