# Joomla blog two categorys side by side

Tags: html, css, joomla, joomla3.3

i am working on a joomla site and want to achieve sth but dont know how to do it.

What I want: If I click on a link in the menu, I want to get a blog-page listing two categorys in two columns. I know its possible to get a blogside listing the articles of 1 category in 2 colums, but I dont know how to to it for multiple categories. I will try to show what I mean cause english is not my main language..:

```
CATEGORY 1 ARTICLE 1   |   CATEGORY 2 ARTICLE 1
CATEGORY 1 ARTICLE 2   |   CATEGORY 2 ARTICLE 2
CATEGORY 1 ARTICLE 3   |   CATEGORY 2 ARTICLE 3
CATEGORY 1 ARTICLE 4   |   CATEGORY 2 ARTICLE 4
...
```

is there a simple way to do this? maybe with an override template or extension? I am using joomla 3.3 with my own template

thanks in advance

Comment: You can only do that using modules. You have to create 2 positions (if doesn't exist) in your template and set 2 modules each one to get articles from one category. Your menu item has to be set up like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25605645/3834042

Comment: Didnt think about modules, will have a look at it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new Module of type "Articles Category" and assigning it to the menu item of your choice.